# before and after in CSS classes

Tags: css

I'm using a css class in order to have a small space before the text starts like this:

```
.this-text:before {
    content: "\00a0 \00a0 ";
}
```

this code works fine, it lets a padding before the text.

The problem comes when I want to add the same thing to the end of the text line.

Firstly, I tried to combine them like this:

```
.this-text:before, .this-text:after {
    content: "\00a0 \00a0 ";
}
```

no result, also no result if I use a separate class for after:

```
.this-text:after {
    content: "\00a0 \00a0 ";
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `.this-text::before, .this-text::after {...}` must work - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjubas1q/) (inspect the element and you'll see the pseudo elements in the DOM).

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen to the end of the text line? Why aren't you using the `padding` style?

Comment: _“Firstly, I tried to combine them like this”_ - what is it with you people always inventing your own fantasy syntax in situations like this ...

Comment: @CBroe I agree, the answer could be found in about 30 seconds, but it's obviously easier to post a question on SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if understood corectly this must work?

> i Added background color on the `:before` and `:after` to see the space it takes up.

```css
p{display: inline-block; }

.this-text::before {
    content: "\00a0 \00a0 ";
    background-color: blue;
}

.this-text::after {
    content: "\00a0 \00a0 ";
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<p class="this-text">text</p><p>text</p>
```

Comment: It is no competition, you know?

Comment: @user4892206 hahaha its not but why be so complicated when it can be so simple bro.

Comment: `.this-text:before, .this-text:after { /*...*/ }` seems to be shorter, isn't it?

Comment: yess in this case "seems to be shorter" , but then adding different colors to explain `::before` and `::after` seems to be harder. For a tip, its not good practice to use them in one line because :before and :after usually dont inherit the same content specs. Maybe he would have liked to put a black background on :before and green on the :after, how would it be accomplished in one line..although its not wrong at all, i think separating them is better practice.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to concatinate `:before` and `:after` correctly with a comma. Have a look at the working example. `background`, `border` and `padding` properties are only for visualisation and can be removed.

```css
div {
  background: #BADBAD;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.this-text:before,
.this-text:after {
  content: "\00a0 \00a0 ";
  background: snow;
}

.this-text,
.another-text {
  border: 1px solid snow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="this-text">This text</span><span class="another-text">Another text</span>
</div>
```